# I installed 23.04 and my wifi adapter is not being found. It worked yesterday in 20.04. How do I fix it?

Tags: wireless

I installed 23.04 today and my wifi adapter no longer works. Anybody know how to fix it?

```
jackstand3@jackstand3-Inspiron-530:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1500 Draft 802.11n WLAN Mini-card [1028:000a]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 1d57:0016 Xenta 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 413c:2105 Dell Computer Corp. Model L100 Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: I experienced the same problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04. In my case the problem was solved by installing **backport-iwlwifi-dkms** Hope this helps.

Comment: It is very doubtful that you have the same Broadcom device.

Answer (score 2):

The upgrade will not install proprietary firmware files, namely those needed for your Broadcom device. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot. You should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping your issue is resolved but if not, I noticed that 23.04 installed a dkms installation of the Broadcom driver which when installed on my MacBookPro didn't work. However what did work is after installing, the initramfs needed re-building. So sudo update-initramfs -u and with any luck you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by installing  backport-iwlwifi-dkms

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Comment: I don’t believe this will solve a Broadcom issue.

Answer (score -1):

The wifi should just work if you do NOT enslave wifi interface to any bridge in your `/etc/netplan/xxx` file. In other words the following fragment in that file cannot work.

```
 ......
   br0:
      - wlan0
```

Ubuntu Linux is known to not support bridging wifi interfaces, so the following simple example should work:

```
network:
   version: 2
   renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
      wlan2:
         dhcp4: yes
         dhcp6: yes
```

After you change this file run:

```
sudo netplan generate 
sudo netplan apply
```

...and you should be good to go.

Comment: found a better solution on the internet (just edited for clarity):